# NullPointerException when using Mockito thenCallRealMethod

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito

I have a question regarding using Mockito thenCallRealMethod.  I've read the warnings about using this function; basically I want to write this into my test to futureproof my application logic, because it's being used as a library and I want to make sure users of my library have futureproof protection.

My test case looks like this:

```
@Test
public void Test() {
    when(restTemplate.postForEntity(...)).thenReturn(new ResponseEntity<>(realObjectMapper.writeValueAsString(data), HttpStatus.OK));
    when(objectMapper.readValue(realObjectMapper.writeValueAsString(data), TestData.class)).thenCallRealMethod();
    TestData result = tested.callMethod(...);
    ....
}
```

TestData is a simple POJO which contains a bunch of fields but nothing particularly interesting, and data is an instance of TestData.  objectMapper is a mocked instance of [FasterXML Jackson ObjectMapper](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.7/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectMapper.html), and realObjectMapper is a real (unmocked) instance of the same class.

The problem I'm having is a NullPointerException when my application attempts to execute objectMapper.readValue (on the mocked instance) as per the thenCallRealMethod on the second line of the test.  I've verified that when I pass the same inputs to realObjectMapper.readValue then it executes fine, so there is nothing wrong with the input.  What am I missing?

```
Stack trace:
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:2842)
    .... (my code here)
```

Comment: can you share you code defining the fields `restTemplate` and `objectMapper ` and the exception stacktrace

Comment: Both restTemplate and objectMapper are simple mocked instances of their respective classes, annotated with @Mock.

I can share the first 2 lines of the stack trace, but the rest would reveal some proprietary code so I'd prefer not to.  OP updated with what I can share.

Comment: you have to give a concrete instance of the `objectMapper` to call real methods on it, `@Mock` won't suffice

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand.  If I can't call real methods on my mock, then what is the point of the thenCallRealMethod() option?

Comment: Ah, I see.  I replaced Mock with Spy on my objectMapper instance and everything worked.  I guess thenCallRealMethod is valid only for instances of Spy and not instances of Mock.

Comment: No so.  It is more likely that the specific method you tried to call relied on some initialization that was present only in the real version of the class.  That would explain why a spy would work.

Comment: yeah, normally a `@Mock` is enough to call also the real methods

Comment: @EJK the exact code executed on the line of code in question is             return objectMapper.readValue(response, expectedReturnType);  Response is the body of an HTTP response which is generated elsewhere in the function, and expectedReturnType is a data type.  Using a debugger, I have verified that none of objectMapper, response, or expectedReturnType is null.

Comment: One possibility is that ObjectMapper itself does some initialization, which is relied on to execute readValue, and the fact that I'm mocking the ObjectMapper means that this internal initialization isn't done.  Does anyone know if this is the case?

Answer (score 2):

**When you use a mocked object then the real object is not initialized. That means any property even with a default value will be null.**

In my case I had a property injected with @Value from a properties file, but if I define a default value it happens the same, it is null when it is going to be used.

Solution: Yo have to check which is the property causing the null pointer exception on the method and then either mock a getter that returns the expected value of that property and call the getter from your real method or set its value with a setter from the test, after the mock object is created